# Questions that change

Tags: selenium

I'm trying to get Selenium to auto run a multi choice question test. However a couple of the question can change to a few different things. For instance question could be pick which one of the below four is a cat. But the next time you run the test it could be pick the one below that is a dog. It only has a few questions that change.

So basically it keeps stopping on the first one that is not the same as when the commands where made. I understand why, but is there a way of asking it to pick something else if the first option is not available so i can just add multi answers to the same command and it would only need to find one of them to continue?

Answer (score 0):

I would build a HashMap of the questions and correct answers as an answer key and then compare the question on the page to the answer key to pick the right answer.

```
HashMap<String, String> answerKey = new HashMap<>();
// you would likely read these from a CSV or maybe an Excel sheet
answerKey.put("Pick the one below that is a cat", "Felix");
answerKey.put("Pick the one below that is a dog", "Spot");


String question = driver.findElement(By.id("questionId")).getText().trim(); // some made up element that contains the question String.
String answer = answerKey.get(question); // look up the answer in the HashMap
// click the element that matches the 'answer' String
```